# What is the Equivalent of "in" in Python on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, jestjs, puppeteer

I am scripting automation in Javascript, using jest and puppeteer right now, and I want to verify a name, for example;

I have a name of `const name = Watson, James R.` and wanted to compare the name `const info_name = Watson James` , which we can hypothetically say that they are the same person. When I was using python and selenium I usually use, `in` just to check the presence of a letter or word inside a string or list, so my question is, what is the best function I can use?

I saw the use of `.includes` but it is too **"case sensitive"** one different character and it gives off **"False"** result. Also I saw `.some` but I get an error of `".some is not a function"`.

What can I use for alternatives? I would gladly appreciate your replies, Thank you in advance!

Comment: post the code that shows the error to you.

Comment: You mean you want to check if substrings of `info_name` (e.g. "Watson") are contained in `name`?

Comment: What you explain sounds like a case insensitive, fuzzy search. I don’t think this exists in js. Can you post examples of what should match and what shouldn’t?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `in` with JavaScript is `.includes`.
In order to ignore case sensitivity you can convert both strings to lower case with `.toLowerCase()` and then apply `.includes`.

```
console.log(string.toLowerCase().includes(substring.toLowerCase()));
```